# Iress feed - Excel and VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I am running a spreadsheet with a whole bunch of stock codes. 
I don't have any problem going via the IRESS addin for excel to get a data feed of prices.

However in my sheet, it gives the option for client to stocks and then it pre-populates a table with information such as stock code, price. However it also is meant to do a calculation of how many units a person would have if they were to invest $x amount into each stock. The problem here is when I run a macro, the iress feed does not refresh and just shows #Value in the cell.

However when I end the macro, the prices start feeding. 
This is what I get:

[image]

The macro breaks when I try to calculate the units.

For formula that the code enters into the cell is:

```
  Cells(i, cp.Column) = "=IRESSRtd( ""Quote"" , ""13"" , ""0"" , "" " & Cells(i, stock.Column) & """)/100"
```

'i' is a loop starting at the first row where there is a stock code, to the lastrow where there is a stock code, then under the "current price" column, it enters that formula.

cp.column is the column reference for 'cp' where 'cp' is set by a .find function. 
Same with the stock.column reference. 
Might be a bit of a long shot, but does anyone know how I can get the Iress feed to update without having to stop my macro?

Comment: As always: (a) Hard to say anything without having a [mcve] or the original code (if it is not too long). And (b) even harder to answer because it is not pure Excel but an issue in combination with a plugin. And (c) we don't know the formulas showing the `#VALUE!`. So due to insufficient information I would say you need a bunch of luck or provide more information (best would be a [mcve]). An issue might be that Excel VBA doesn't support multi-threading. So I'm not sure if a plugin code and a macro can run at the same time at all.

Comment: As Peh mentioned it is hard to help you without your code. But check your macro for settings like Calculation=xlManual, or application.screenupdating=false. These kind of things might prevent your sheet from updating.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for the responses. I have added the formula into my example above. I have tried to run this same code in it's simplest form, however the cell remains as #Value until the macro completely ends.

Comment: (a) did you check what Luuklag said? (b) As I already said VBA doesn't support multi-threading (means it can only run macros sequentially one after another but not at the same time). So it might be possible (I'm not 100 % sure about this) that an add-in and a macro can not be executed at the same time. Therefore do some research into this direction, probably best at the add-in website or its community.

Answer (score 0):

IRESS support recommends to either use the UI of the Excel addin to generate the RTD links, or if you really want to do a lot more number crunching in the VBA you could call the IRESS API directly - i.e. IRESS Server API COM interface calling the PricingQuoteGet method (with Updates enabled). There is a sample on getting quote info back in the IRESS help files ”IRESS PRO FE > Help | API Documentation | IRESS Server API | Programmer's Guide